# how to prevent column from from breaking when using gutters, Jeet

Tags: css, stylus, jeet-grid

I am trying to have four columns using jeet and a gutter of .5

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 1/4)
```

This causes the fourth column to break to a new row, giving me only 3 columns. I tried it without a gutter and the same thing happens.

```
col(1/4, cycle: 1/4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cycle` is your blocks/row value, as such it should be an integer:

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 4)
```

Comment: could you accept the answer please, il will help other users with the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I had different columns and gutters for different resolutions and I had to uncycle everything before setting a new cycle for another resolution, e.g.

```
@include col(1/2, $gutter: 2, $cycle: 2);
@media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint2) { 
    @include col(1/3, $gutter: 3, $uncycle: 2, $cycle: 3); 
}
```